# The advantage of using base biasing over emitter biasing?

Tags: transistors, bjt, bias, emitter-follower

Can someone please explain to me what is the advantage of using base biasing over emitter biasing. Why is a 'feedback resistor' used in base biasing?

Comment: It would be better to edit your question to add a link to the tutorial that has confused you, then we can see where you are, and go forward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One major parameter which decide biasing in BJT transistors is **Bias Stability**. As β (hFE) widely varies from transistor to transistor. An stable biasing will provide minimum alteration in the Q-point on wide changes in β.

Mathematically stability factor is denoted by,

S= delta Ic / delta Icb.

S depends on the circuit configuration and
the bias resistors. S should be as small as possible.

Consider the thress biasing,
[image]

[image]

[image]

Now you can choose a biasing with low value of 'S' for better stability.

We never desire high value of 'S'. If one of the transistor stop working in your design then it's replacemnt may not have the same Beta. You want least effect on the Q-point due to the error in beta value. So need a low value of 'S'.

Consider these calculations:
[image]

**VCEQ changes by 41% when β changes by 50%.**
[image]

**VCEQ changes by 25% when β changes by 50%.**

[image]

**VCEQ changes by 6% when β changes by 50%.**

Comment: Perhaps, in addition, it should be mentioned if a high or a low S value is desired. Are we interested in a large or a lower value of Delta(Ic)?

Comment: Thanks, for your answer.  Can you please tell me what is the role of the feedback resistor?

Comment: So low S is good ,.....so what makes base bias "good" ?!

Comment: No - of course, we desire to have a LOW S value. This is because S is proportional to (delta Ic) - and we want to have a small dependence of Ic on variations of transistor parameters and temperature. As a consequence, voltage divider biasing with Re feedback is the best alternative.

Comment: @LvW @ Autistic You all are right that we need Low value of S. answer has been corrected. thanks or pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is simple which you have to fix in your mind that we bias transistor in order to make Operating point (Q-point) stable so that we could get faithful Amplification.

Now as Operating point depends on two factors, 1) Collector Current Ic 2) Voltage a=across collector and emitter Vce.

So in base bias we we analyze input part we get a base current, we get base current as we know Ic = Beta(Ib).

When we analyze output part we get Vce = Vcc - IcRc.

Now from above we notice Ic depends on Beta while Vce dependes on Ic , so variation in Beta will cause variation in both Ic and Vce.

And we know Beta varies with external temprature effect, so as beta will vary due to this external effect so both Ic and Vce will also vary hence the operating point (Q-point) will also varies which means it become unstable. So thats why we always need a fixed middle Q point for transistor but in base bias it varies due to external temprature effect so we dont use this base bias.

We use emitter bias because in this Q point can get stable with a condition if we take base voltage is equal to zero or Rb = 0, Thanks. Hope you will understand it furthermore i will also be enageged in comment section for further queries.